# Background Texture Not Showing In Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a website using the Flat UI Twitter Bootstrap mod. While trying to set a background texture, I have found that it is not visible. Here is my CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(img/texture.png);
}
```

Can someone help me to get my background texture to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details, the first thing I would check is the path to the texture.png image. Since its a background image, the url is relative to your stylesheet.

So say your your CSS is in the website/css folder and the texture is in the website/images folder, your CSS would be more like:

```
body
{
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(../images/img/texture.png);
}
```

If you know how to use the web inspector or something similar on most browsers, it will help to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I had thought that since the stylesheet was initialized from the html document, it act as if it were running from it, like in a heiarchy, but I was wrong. Thanks again!